# how expensive is SSL for a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, ssl, https, facebook

I am making a RESTful API and am wondering how computationally expensive it is for the server if each request is done using SSL? It's probably hard to quantify, but a comparison to non-SSL requests would be useful (e.g. 1 SSL is as expensive as 30 non-SSL request).

Am I right in thinking that for an SSL connection to be established, both parties need to generate public and private keys, share them with each other, and then start communicating. If when using a RESTful API, does this process happen on each request? Or is there some sort of caching that reuses a key for a given host for a given period of time (if so, how long before they expire?).

And one last question, the reason I am asking is because I am making an app that uses facebook connect, and there are some access tokens involved which grant access to someone's facebook account, having said that, why does facebook allow transmitting these access tokens over non-encrypted connections? Surely they should guard the access tokens as strongly as the username/passwd combos, and as such enforce an SSL connection... yet they don't.

EDIT: facebook does in fact enforce a HTTPS connection whenever the access_token is being transmitted.

Comment: To answer your last question: they **should** require an SSL connection for anything that contains secret information, such as access tokens. Facebook, however, is not noted for their dedication to privacy.

Comment: @Cameron, it turns out they do require you to connect over https when the access token is being transmitted. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html

> On our [Google's, ed.] production frontend machines, SSL/TLS accounts for less than 1% of the CPU load, less than 10KB of memory per connection and less than 2% of network overhead. Many people believe that SSL takes a lot of CPU time and we hope the above numbers (public for the first time) will help to dispel that.
>
> If you stop reading now you only need to remember one thing: SSL/TLS is not computationally expensive any more.

Comment: Thats interesting. But i think one should take into account that server machines most normally do  no certificate verification (which can be expensive if done correctly).

Answer (score 1):

SSL process is roughly as follows:

- Server (and optionally client) present their (existing, not generated) public key using a certificate, together with a signed challenge. The opposite party verifies the signature (its mathematical validity, the certificate path up to the CA, the revocation status,...) to be sure the opposite party is who it claims to be.
- Between the authenticated parties a secret session key is negotiated (for example using the Diffie Hellman algorithm).
- The parties switch to encrypted communication

This is an expensive protocol up to here and happens every time a socket is established. You can not cache a check about "who's on the other side". This is why you should persistent sockets (event with REST).

Comment: This is not exactly the way you described - TLS supports session resuming which eliminates the need for complete handshake to be performed each time.

Comment: I'd just like to emphasise the fact that the public/private key pair is only generated **once**, not once per connection. This is important because generating public/private key pairs is very expensive, but the session key negotiation is much less so.

Comment: @Cameron private/public keys are not generated during handshake at all.

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, that's correct. They are generated once, offline.

Comment: TLS is a complicated protocol with many options. For ciphersuites that include DHE, a new DH public/private keypair is generated for *every* new (not resumed) connection, and by both sides.

Comment: @GregS that's theory - in some ciphersuites public/private keypair is not used at all, but we are not talking about these rare cases such as DHE or SRP

Comment: @Eugene: DHE ciphersuites are very commonly used on the internet, because Apache supports them on the server side and Opera and Firefox support them on the browser side and *prefer* them to non-DHE ciphersuites. Neither IE nor IIS supports them however, so if either peer is one of the products then you won't have DHE cipheruites

Comment: @GregS I am wondering, what percentage of *total* (not just HTTPS) SSL/TLS traffic the combination of Apache+Opera/Firefox makes. I bet it's minimal.

Comment: @Eugene: How can we know? I'll bet it's more than 10% of HTTPS though. Apache and Firefox are a reasonably common combination.

Comment: @GregS Yes, it's significant part of HTTPS (smth. about 25-30% I guess). Yet it's not clear, what part of total SSL traffic is made by HTTPS. It would be interesting to find such stats, but probably tomorrow. Happy new year!

Comment: @Eugene: Happy new year to you also.

Answer (score 1):

mtraut described the way SSL works, yet he omited the fact that TLS *supports* session resuming. However, even as the session resuming is supported by the protocol itself and many conformant servers, it's not always supported by client-side implementations. So you should not rely on resuming and you better keep a persistent session where possible.

On the other hand, SSL handshake is quite fast (about a dozen of milliseconds) nowadays so it's not the biggest bottleneck in most cases.

Comment: I am not so intimate with these protocols. But i can't imagine how a session resume can take place if not on the identical socket connection. THere must be a re-authentication anyway (except the socket is not closed, as said). Do i miss something?

Comment: @mtraut I don't know the details that deep, our developers do. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt, F.1.4 will help you.

Comment: @mtraut: The socket has nothing to do with it. Sessions are most frequently resumed on new sockets. As Eugene says, the details can be found in the RFCs. However, I recommend you just watch your own connections with wireshark and see what happens.

Comment: @GregS, this may be bad style - in this case i apologize. You seem to have sound basics in this area. I have a related question that starves here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552978/security-review-of-an-authenticated-diffie-hellman-variant..  Maybe have a look?

Comment: @mtraut: Sorry, I mostly stick to explaining existing protocols, APIs, and documented attacks. I don't do original analysis.